# Oracle source with SSIS 2008

Tags: oracle, ssis, oledb, ssis-2008

I am trying to use an Oracle OleDb source in my SSIS package with no luck, every time I try to connect to the server I get the error:

> ORA-12154 tns could not resolve the connect identifier specified

, knowing that:

1 I installed Oracle 11g express edition

2 I added an entry for the alias in my tnsnames.ora file

3 ORACLE_HOME variable pointing to my Oracle installation

4 Path & TNS_ADMIN variables pointing to the directory containing the tnsnames.ora file

5 I am using a Windows Server 2012

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My bet is on 32 vs. 64 Bit OleDb driver issue.

Comment: @Filburt  how can I resolve this?

Comment: Use the x64 cmd (the one you simply open Win Start Menu) and the 32-Bit (the one located at C:\Windows\SySWOW64\cmd.exe) and try [tnsping](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1066143?start=0&tstart=0) your Oracle database instance. This will show which drivers work and which don't. Since Visual Studio for SSIS 2008 is a 32-Bit process, it cannot "see" x64 Oracle OleDb drivers.

Comment: I think your answer is helping me currently, because through the tnsping, I could find which tnsnames.ora file was being used, and configured it.

Comment: I still haven't tried with an SSIS package, due to network related problems, can you please put your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the solution when I test.

Comment: Just put your findings and solution steps as an answer - no need for extra credit for me.